# c# - Automatic repeat of one task until another is finished

Tags: asynchronous, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task

I have two operations - `Download()` and  `Upload()`. I was running them in parallel using `TAP` and returning results as they both finish :

```
var task_download = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Download());
var task_Upload = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Upload());
var tasks = new Task[] { task_download, task_Upload };
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Here If one task is finished and another didn't it will wait both to get finished and move on

But the problem for me is let say there are 100 files to `Download()` and 50 files to `Upload()`. After 50 files upload the task will wait for the `Download()` function to complete. In the mean time if some more files came for `Upload()` in the queue it won't take because of this and vice-versa for download. Is there any way to do this?

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: If you have a queue of files, why is there no loop in your tasks or around your tasks?

Comment: @nvoigt so the task will continue both loop got finished at the same time?